# Sharepoint doing an automatic discard checkout - losing changes!

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-api

Scenario:

1. Through web interface, I check out and edit a file.
2. I exit my (non-office) application.  My application asks if I wish to check in, and I reply no.  Document with my changes remains checked out, present in my SharePoint Drafts folder, and present in the registry under HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\Common\Offline\Files
3. I go back to the web interface, click the name of the file, am prompted to view the file. I click "OK" and, to my horror, an automatic discard of the checkout is performed:
   a. Registry entry deleted
   b. File (WITH MY PRECIOUS CHANGES) is unceremoniously deleted

What I would have *hoped* is that a redirect would have happened to launch my application with the modified draft in the SharePoint Drafts folder.

Does anyone know how to get SharePoint to perform this?

UPDATE:  I discovered that if I upload the file (without checking it in) through SharePoint web services, SharePoint no longer performs this "discard checkout" at the next read attempt by the same user.

Comment: What application if it is an off the shelf product?

Comment: It's my organization's application. I'm fairly certain it's not responsible for this.  I deleted its .exe prior to step 3, and watched as the file and the registry entry were deleted.

Comment: Is anything changing with the filename held in the registry or your SP drafts folder?